# Jquery in Custom HTML Helper Extensions to pick value from the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have used this custom Helper in My Razor View.

```
  @Html.Link("OpenewWindow", Constants.Value, new { k = Constants.k, Staff_ID = LoginHelper.GetLoggedInUser() }, new { id = "mytag", target="_blank" })
```

When I Click on this link it opens me a new window with the Querystrings `ConstantValue/Constants?=someValue&Staff_ID=UserLoggedName.`

I want to pick the radio button selected value on the form and pass the checked value in QueryString.

So where can I use Jquery function in my custom Helper method to pick the value from the form.

The Custom Helper method takes this kind of aurguments.

```
 public static IHtmlString Link(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string baseUrl, object query, object htmlAttributes).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to do that. For example you could subscribe to the `click` event of the link and then open a popup window by appending the new query string parameter:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_link').click(function() {
        var url = this.href;
        if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            url += '&';
        } else {
            url += '?';
        }

        // get the value of the radio button
        var value = $(':radio[name="name_of_your_radio_groups"]:checked').val();
        url += url + 'radiovalue=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
        window.open(url, 'newwindow');

        // cancel the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you don't need to use javascript then a cleaner approach is to use a form instead of a link. This way the value of the selected radio button will automatically be sent.